# jQuery plugins inside a angularjs routing page

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working with the angularjs, but im actually just using the routing function.
My questing is, how do i implement jquery plugins inside a dynamic content?

Let's say my html document looks like this:

index.html

```
 <html>

<div ng-view=""></div>

<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="plugin1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="plugin2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="plugin_charts.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

</html>
```

File_to_load_dynamic.html

```
<div id="get_charts_created_in_plugin_just_like_if_this_was_in_index.html"></div>
```

The div just won't get infected.. And I can't really use jQuery inside the file, but when i check if it's loaded, it is.. Just not working..

Please help me, it's driving my crazy!

Thanks!